# Django - set model field to the DB "Now" value in a model method

Tags: django, postgresql

I am trying to set one of the model's DateTime fields to "now". To avoid any time difference issues, I am trying to stick to the time values generated in the DB (as opposed to those generated in Python, like `datetime.datetime.now()`). However, it looks like it is difficult to do it from within an instance method. I am trying to do something like the below:

```
class MyModel:
    ...
    last_fetched = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    def fetch_scenes(self):
        # Do some work
        ...
        self.objects.filter(id=self.id).update(last_fetched=django.db.models.functions.Now())
```

Django does not allow accessing the model's manager from within instance methods (probably for a good reason). Is there any way to access and update the query set consisting of the instance alone?

Comment: That wouldn't work even if you could access `self.objects`, because `.get` returns an instance (which would be equivalent to `self`).

Comment: You are right! Replaced with `.filter` to make the question more sensible.

Answer (score 0):

Move the method to the [model's manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#from-queryset). Then you can access the queryset as you expect it to here.